# Filtering noise with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, pattern-recognition

I was wondering if it could be possible to filter noise in an image using machine learning techniques. In my concrete case, I have important information as points (of the same size) that form a diagonal and a lot of noise in form of ""random"" points like a genome comparison (see figure 1).

For sure, there are ¿simpler? techniques to do that. I have implemented myself a simple heuristic to clean the image, for example, but It could be done using ML? maybe like a dataset with diagonals and other with random points? I usually use tensorflow so, if you know about something similar already implemented, it could be great to see it.

[image: Genome comparison]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) can be used for [Image Denoising (Xie)](http://Image%20Denoising%20and%20Inpainting%20with%20Deep%20Neural%20Networks) with exceptional results.  Essentially, imagine a network where the input is your image (NxN) and the output is of the same dimension (NxN).  If the hidden layer were the same or a greater dimension, the network would simply memorize your image.  *However*, if you make the hidden layer smaller than your image, it must compress it.  In this compression process, it removes noise.  Not sure if it's good, but [here](http://blackecho.github.io/blog/machine-learning/2016/02/29/denoising-autoencoder-tensorflow.html) is a tutorial in TF.  Also see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAv9K4U39oc).